# wxWidgets Wizard sample runtime crash

Tags: c++, crash, wxwidgets, wizard, sample

The complete code is more than 400 line. You can find it here: http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/4122 or if you have wxwidgets installed then under **WX_WIDGETS_ROOT\samples\wizard\wizard.cpp**.

I tried to compile it but get 
"error C2065: 'm_bitmap' : undeclared identifier" on line 122.

Then I commented that line and it compiles ok. But when I run it and select one of these menu commands:

- File >> Run wizard modal
- File >> Run wizard withour sizer
- File >>
  Run wizard modeless

it goes to MyWizard constructor and crashes on m_page1 = new... line.

```
MyWizard::MyWizard(wxFrame *frame, bool useSizer)
    : wxWizard(frame,wxID_ANY,_T("Absolutely Useless Wizard"),
    wxBitmap(wiztest_xpm),wxDefaultPosition,
    wxDEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE | wxRESIZE_BORDER)
{
    // a wizard page may be either an object of predefined class
    m_page1 = new wxWizardPageSimple(this);<---------------- HERE
```

and gave this error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x004425ec in wizard.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
>   violation reading location 0xcdcdcdd1.

I checked in debugger and saw that it goes to

```
void wxWizardPage::Init()
{
    m_bitmap = wxNullBitmap;<--- HERE
}
```

and then a few inner calls later trying to access m_refData->m_count where m_refData contains garbage m_refData = 0xcdcdcdcd {m_count=??? } and then crashed.

```
void wxObject::UnRef()
{
    if ( m_refData )
    {
        wxASSERT_MSG( m_refData->m_count > 0, _T("invalid ref data count") );<----- HERE

        if ( --m_refData->m_count == 0 )
            delete m_refData;
        m_refData = NULL;
    }
}
```

Here is call stack if it will be useful:

> wizard.exe!wxObject::UnRef()  Line 346 + 0x6 bytes  C++ 
>     wizard.exe!wxObject::Ref(const wxObject & clone)  Line 335  C++ 
>     wizard.exe!wxObject::operator=(const wxObject & other)  Line 428    C++ 
>     wizard.exe!wxGDIObject::operator=(const wxGDIObject & __that)  + 0x13
>   bytes C++     wizard.exe!wxGDIImage::operator=(const wxGDIImage &
>   __that)  + 0x13 bytes C++     wizard.exe!wxBitmap::operator=(const wxBitmap & __that)  + 0x13 bytes   C++
>
> > wizard.exe!wxWizardPage::Init()  Line 126   C++     wizard.exe!wxWizardPage::wxWizardPage()  Line 50 + 0x46 bytes   C++ 
> >       wizard.exe!wxWizardPageSimple::wxWizardPageSimple(wxWizard * parent,
> >     wxWizardPage * prev, wxWizardPage * next, const wxBitmap & bitmap,
> >     const char * resource)  Line 113 + 0x2e bytes C++ 
> >       wizard.exe!MyWizard::MyWizard(wxFrame * frame, bool useSizer)  Line
> >     376 + 0x31 bytes  C++

Comment: There is something seriously wrong with your wxWidgets installation, probably a version mismatch, as `m_bitmap` should exist in the base class. Check that you're using the library you think you're using and rebuild everything once again if in doubt.

Comment: You were right. After building wxWidgets again the problem was solved.